# Javascript - Fill canvas with image on clicking a image from gallery

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I have a image gallery populated with images using PHP from a local directory.  I want to select an image by clicking on it and displaying it on a canvas to enable users to draw on the image.

The gallery is generated using php and the following are parts of html and php codes

HTML

```
<div id="loaded_img_panel" name="loaded_img_panel" class="dragscroll" >           
</div>
```

PHP:

```
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" id="thumbNails"/>';
```

I am able to display images without a trouble.

I have created a canvas to display the image.

HTML-CANVAS

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

The following is the javascript that I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.load = function() {
     var image = document.getElementById("thumbNails");
     image.addEventListener("click", fetchImage);

       function fetchImage(e) {
         fill_canvas(image).src = e.target.src
         }
       function fill_canvas(img) {
         var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

         canvas.width = img.width();
         canvas.height = img.height();

         ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0)
        }
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: Did you find any error in log ?

Comment: `fill_canvas ` does not return a element to set `src` of...

Comment: @Rayon No errors....are there any alternatives?

Comment: You must be using `window.onload` instead of `window.load`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using `window.onload` instead of `window.load`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var image = document.getElementById("thumbNails");
  image.addEventListener("click", fetchImage);

  function fetchImage(e) {
    fill_canvas(image);
  }

  function fill_canvas(img) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loaded_img_panel" name="loaded_img_panel" class="dragscroll">
</div>
<hr>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<hr>
<img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/9841060568868240804" id="thumbNails" width="100" />
```

Comment: Thank you..but i am not able to display the image on my site canvas....though your example surely works

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it is working. I will check my codes and confirm to you.

Comment: Thank you again.  I figured out how to resolve displaying a image on click from a gallery.  Have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  This is how I resolved this.

```
 window.onload = function() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
            canvas = x.getContext('2d');
            var thumbNails = document.getElementById("loaded_img_panel");
            var pic = new Image();
            thumbNails.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                pic.src = event.target.src;
                pic.addEventListener("load", function(){canvas.drawImage(pic,0,0)})
            }, false); 
          }
```

Instead of using my image id which was thumbNail, I used the div id of my image gallery.